# How to host Strapi using distroless image in Docker without using npm command?

Tags: node.js, docker, strapi

I am trying to host a Strapi instance in a Docker container using a distroless image. As I am using a distroless image, I cannot use the npm command to run Strapi. Is there an equivalent of the `strapi start` command that can be run purely using Node?

Here is my summarised Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build
# Build steps
# ...

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:16 as host
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

As I mentioned, this Dockerfile cannot be used with a distroless image since it uses npm command in the CMD line. What changes should I make to my Dockerfile to use Strapi with a distroless image without using the npm command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the right path is `./node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js`

Here's the updated Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:16 as host
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["./node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js", "start"]
```

Take note that you should not use alpine to build the application when you are using distroless. Use the node base image.

```
FROM node:16.20 as build
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the CMD command with the one that you have in your package.json.

I would assume that would be: `yarn start`

```
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

For references about CMD: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: This doesn't work given I'm using a distroless image